# CSS Drop Down Menu Error in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

Link to example image (IE9) [imageshack-ie9dropdownerror](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/716/cssdropdownieerror.png/)

I'm designing a website for a friend and I'm having a drop down menu error specific to internet explorer (ie8 & ie9 for sure - ie7 and below not tested). You can go to the website via http://test.tjpsconsulting.com and look at the source code (css and html) - main navigation menu and style.css.

Parts of the menu drop down, but none of the links (quasi-transparent).

I've been making changes here and there, but can't quite figure out what could be causing the problem - whether it's IE related or positioning related, etc etc.  Perhaps I've been looking at it too long.

Not sure if I should use a js fix or not... would rather avoid if possible.

Comment: What version of IE (makes a big difference)?

Comment: so far both ie8 and ie9 - haven't tried ie7 or below

Comment: I figured it out: "filter" css property error.  I hate Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out: "filter" css property error - once I removed it, problem solved.  Now instead of "filter" to create gradient I just call a .gif image (and use "if" statement to create class for ie). I hate Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems like that in the past, it all depends on what IE version you're using most of the web-kit elements tend to have problems inside older versions of IE. I created a modal box using html, css and javascript and it wouldn't work in IE 7 or below and this fix was a css fix within the css body tag. Just google if theres a fix for older browsers :)

Comment: No, I'm having trouble getting the drop down menu to appear properly in ie8 and ie9, and I have yet to test in ie7 or below (I imagine it doesn't work in them either). It does display properly in current versions of chrome and firefox.

Comment: Oh, okay IE isn't that great anyhow it's on most computers :P